# Несколько post parent для цикла WP?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
        $stati_children = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post_parent' => 72
            )
          );
        ?>
      <?php if($stati_children->have_posts()) :
....
```

Но как сделать что бы вместо post_parent => 72, дать больше значений. Надо что бы цикл брал из несколько parent страниц, 72,105,320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выведит посты родители которых указаны в массиве:

```
'post_parent__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 )
```

Выведит только указанные посты:

```
'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 )
```